# Css background Wont work?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I have a question.

I am currently building a "blog" website. Not that it matters but..
I am trying to set my background to be a specific image that i have.
And it used to work! Until recently and I just don't know why it wont.

It works when i am on my computer, everything works fine.
But i am using 000Webhost as the hoster for the website.
So if u go to "http://pontuslundhblogg.uphero.com/"

You might see that the website is completely white. Cause the picture wont load for the background.
In my css sheet, i am using:

***body {

    background-image: url("bakgrund.jpg");***

And yes, i did name the picture bakgrund.jpg and uploaded it to 000webhost. Its the exact same name etc. I wondering.. Could two different css stylesheets make so it gets weird or something? Cause I added a second css style sheet to be able to have a drop-down menu in a different sheet, and i added the drop-menu. Around that time it started messing with me..

Is it me doing something wrong.
Or is it 000Webhost?

*(Might add that none of my pictures is working now, i can also contribute with more code if needed!*)

Comment: That's because it can't find the image... You have to specify the correct path to the image to show it.

Comment: If you go to http://pontuslundhblogg.uphero.com/bakgrund.jpg you get a message "The image http://pontuslundhblogg.uphero.com/bakgrund.jpg cannot be displayed because it contains errors".  So the image does exist and I guess the path is right but the image itself isn't good. Try to upload it again

Comment: bakgrund.jpg spelling mistake..??? it could be bakground.jpg

Comment: make sure your path is correct?

Comment: looks like the image is corrupted

Comment: @Tushar Gupta: I changed the name of the picture, and it still didnt work. (It's in swedish, thats why :))

Comment: @Siyah should'nt it be enough with just background.jpg ? Since they are on the same ftp? Or same host?

Comment: @Kleinohad then how do i fix that?
Cause i just tried to download the picture from the website.. Then it says i cant open it.. D:

Comment: And I also tried to upload it again, still didnt work..
But it still works on my computer.. Is it possibly it gets corrupted when i add it on the host?

Comment: Its a 1.1 MB file!! The response tells this: "*Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Windows)2014:10:10 17:59:29� 2008 Alexander-GGhttp://alexander-gg.deviantart.com*". It seems that perhaps your image is not actually a jpeg but some other format renamed to jpeg.

Comment: @Pontus-Lundh you need to load a new file to your hosting service to replace the current image file

Comment: If the image is really 1.1MB it's really bad for a background....

Comment: Its 1.1mb just because i saved it in the best quality..
I tried to remake it now, making it 500kb - and with another name, still wont work (I replaced everything on the host)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to  [pontuslundhblogg.uphero.com/bakgrund.jpg](http://pontuslundhblogg.uphero.com/bakgrund.jpg) you get a message

> "The image pontuslundhblogg.uphero.com/bakgrund.jpg cannot be
>   displayed because it contains errors".

If you go to  [pontuslundhblogg.uphero.com/bakgrund1.jpg](http://pontuslundhblogg.uphero.com/bakgrund.jpg) you get 404 page, which means that the first path (bakgrund.jpg) is correct - but the image itself isn't good.

Try to upload it again or contact the hosting service.

If you use FTP maybe you need to change something in your FTP program settings - maybe change from ASCII to Binary transfer.
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/file-management/corrupt-file-ftp-transfer

Comment: You should also get rid of the `background` attribute (which is deprecated) from your body tag and rely on the `background-image` in your CSS instead. Also worth noting that the `url("bakgrund.jpg")` means "bakgrund.jpg in the same folder as this CSS file", so if you move either of them the URL will no longer be correct.

Comment: Im gonna give this a try.. (changing the binary)

Comment: The CSS and the picture itself is in the same folder.
And I hence the background-image in the css.. But what do you mean by background in my body tag?

Comment: Did you change to binary and uploaded the image again? The problem is not with the path. your FTP is somehow corrupt your image and you need to find out why. Maybe you should try another FTP program. Anyway use binary mode because ascii will corrupt your images.

Comment: ok Tamar.. You were actually right.
I tried using their other FTP function(Wich i never used before) and re-added ALL the files i had on the website.. Making it work. But then it actually said: 
"has been transferred to the FTP server using FTP mode FTP_BINARY"*
"has been transferred to the FTP server using FTP mode FTP_ASCII"
On some of them like the images.. So im guessing that was indeed the problem.. Thanks!